# Creating anonymous objects in php

Tags: php, oop, object

As we know, creating anonymous objects in JavaScript is easy, like the code below:

```
var object = { 
    p : "value", 
    p1 : [ "john", "johnny" ]
};

alert(object.p1[1]);
```

Output:

```
an alert is raised with value "johnny"
```

Can this same technique be applied in PHP? Can we create anonymous objects in PHP?

Comment: Note: this is an old question, so the accepted answer is out-of-date. This feature being asked for has now been added to PHP 7. See the answer below by @Rizier123.

Comment: @Simba - Thanks for pointing it out. Would you like to post an answer on StackOverflow here on this page to help future visitors?

Comment: I don't need to; there is already an answer with this info (see below, by @Rizier123).

Comment: That answer doesn't answer the question at all though? Not sure why it's marked as accepted.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It has been some years, but I think I need to keep the information up to date!

Since PHP 7 it has been possible to create anonymous classes, so you're able to do things like this:

```
<?php

    class Foo {}
    $child = new class extends Foo {};

    var_dump($child instanceof Foo); // true

?>
```

You can read more about this [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php)

But I don't know how similar it is implemented to JavaScript, so there may be a few differences between anonymous classes in JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: @risyasin Thanks, updated the answer and put the manual link in it.

Comment: Marking your answer as correct to keep up with latest changes in php7. Thanks @Rizier123

Comment: This is interesting but it doesn't really address the question, as the OP was asking about a convenient way to initialise an object with various members without creating a class. I am not sure whether anonymous classes in php can be used to do that, and if it can, you didn't explain how.

Answer (score 245):

"Anonymous" is not the correct terminology when talking about objects. It would be better to say "object of anonymous *type*", but this does not apply to PHP.

All objects in PHP have a class. The "default" class is [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php), and you can create objects of it this way:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->aProperty = 'value';
```

You can also take advantage of [casting an array to an object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) for a more convenient syntax:

```
$obj = (object)array('aProperty' => 'value');
print_r($obj);
```

However, be advised that casting an array to an object is likely to yield "interesting" results for those array keys that are not valid PHP variable names -- for example, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers/10333200#10333200) an answer of mine that shows what happens when keys begin with digits.

Comment: can i push multiple valued array also?

Comment: @CodingFreak: You can, **but**: if the array contains sub-arrays and you want those as objects as well, you will need to cast every one to object explicitly.

Answer (score 30):

Up until recently this is how I created objects on the fly.

```
$someObj = json_decode("{}");
```

Then:

```
$someObj->someProperty = someValue;
```

But now I go with:

```
$someObj = (object)[];
```

Then like before:

```
$someObj->someProperty = someValue;
```

Of course if you already know the properties and values you can set them inside as has been mentioned:

```
$someObj = (object)['prop1' => 'value1','prop2' => 'value2'];
```

NB: I don't know which versions of PHP this works on so you would need to be mindful of that. But I think the first approach (which is also short if there are no properties to set at construction) should work for all versions that have json_encode/json_decode

Comment: How's that different from going $someObj = new \stdClass()?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, it is possible! Using this simple [PHP Anonymous Object](https://gist.github.com/3700483) class. How it works:

```
// define by passing in constructor
$anonim_obj = new AnObj(array(
    "foo" => function() { echo "foo"; }, 
    "bar" => function($bar) { echo $bar; } 
));

$anonim_obj->foo(); // prints "foo"
$anonim_obj->bar("hello, world"); // prints "hello, world"

// define at runtime
$anonim_obj->zoo = function() { echo "zoo"; };
$anonim_obj->zoo(); // prints "zoo"

// mimic self 
$anonim_obj->prop = "abc";
$anonim_obj->propMethod = function() use($anonim_obj) {
    echo $anonim_obj->prop; 
};
$anonim_obj->propMethod(); // prints "abc"
```

Of course this object is an instance of `AnObj` class, so it is not really anonymous, but it makes possible to define methods on the fly, like JavaScript do.

Comment: You can use [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to emulate anonymous function.

Comment: I think he just wanted a neat way to initialise a stdClass object with some values. Can you do that with your approach?

Answer (score 12):

**Convert array to object** *(but this is not recursive to sub-children)*:

```
$obj = (object)  ['myProp' => 'myVal'];
```

Comment: Please do not use bold.

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to mimic JavaScript, you can create a class `Object`, and thus get the same behaviour. Of course this isn't quite anonymous anymore, but it will work.

```
<?php 
class Object { 
    function __construct( ) { 
        $n = func_num_args( ) ; 
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i += 2 ) { 
            $this->{func_get_arg($i)} = func_get_arg($i + 1) ; 
        } 
    } 
} 

$o = new Object( 
    'aProperty', 'value', 
    'anotherProperty', array('element 1', 'element 2')) ; 
echo $o->anotherProperty[1];
?>
```

That will output *element 2*. This was stolen from [a comment on PHP: Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php#53282).

Answer (score 5):

Support for [anonymous classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) has been available since PHP 7.0, and is the closest analogue to the JavaScript example provided in the question.

```
<?php
$object = new class {
    var $p = "value";
    var $p1 = ["john", "johnny"];
};

echo $object->p1[1];
```

The visibility declaration on properties cannot be omitted (I just used `var` because it's shorter than `public`.)

Like JavaScript, you can also define methods for the class:

```
<?php
$object = new class {
    var $p = "value";
    var $p1 = ["john", "johnny"];
    function foo() {return $this->p;}
};

echo $object->foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

Anoynmus object  [wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes)

```
$object=new class (){


};
```

Answer (score 1):

For one who wants a recursive object:

```
$o = (object) array(
    'foo' => (object) array(
        'sub' => '...'
    )
);

echo $o->foo->sub;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP documentation, few more examples:

```
<?php

$obj1 = new \stdClass; // Instantiate stdClass object
$obj2 = new class{}; // Instantiate anonymous class
$obj3 = (object)[]; // Cast empty array to object

var_dump($obj1); // object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}
var_dump($obj2); // object(class@anonymous)#2 (0) {}
var_dump($obj3); // object(stdClass)#3 (0) {}

?>
```

$obj1 and $obj3 are the same type, but $obj1 !== $obj3. Also, all three will json_encode() to a simple JS object {}:

```
<?php

echo json_encode([
    new \stdClass,
    new class{},
    (object)[],
]);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create object (like in javascript) with dynamic properties, without receiving a warning of undefined property, when you haven't set a value to property

```
class stdClass {

public function __construct(array $arguments = array()) {
    if (!empty($arguments)) {
        foreach ($arguments as $property => $argument) {
            if(is_numeric($property)):
                $this->{$argument} = null;
            else:
                $this->{$property} = $argument;
            endif;
        }
    }
}

public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    $arguments = array_merge(array("stdObject" => $this), $arguments); // Note: method argument 0 will always referred to the main class ($this).
    if (isset($this->{$method}) && is_callable($this->{$method})) {
        return call_user_func_array($this->{$method}, $arguments);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdObject::{$method}()");
    }
}

public function __get($name){
    if(property_exists($this, $name)):
        return $this->{$name};
    else:
        return $this->{$name} = null;
    endif;
}

public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->{$name} = $value;
}

}

$obj1 = new stdClass(['property1','property2'=>'value']); //assign default property
echo $obj1->property1;//null
echo $obj1->property2;//value

$obj2 = new stdClass();//without properties set
echo $obj2->property1;//null
```

Answer (score -1):

> Can this same technique be applied in case of PHP?

No - because javascript uses prototypes/direct declaration of objects - in PHP (and many other OO languages) an object can only be created from a class.

So the question becomes - can you create an anonymous class.

Again the answer is no - how would you instantiate the class without being able to reference it?

Comment: You don't need a name to create an instance of an anonymous class. Java: `Object var = new Object() { ... };` -- C++: `class { ... } var;`

Comment: You can create anonymous classes in PHP now.