# Declaring an anonymous function within new stdClass

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Just wondering why something like this doesn't work:

```
public function address($name){
    if(!isset($this->addresses[$name])){
        $address = new stdClass();
        $address->city = function($class = '', $style = ''){
            return $class;
        };          
        $this->addresses[$name] = $address;
    }
    return $this->addresses[$name];
}
```

Calling it like `echo $class->address('name')->city('Class')` should just echo `Class`, however I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::city()`

I can find a better way to do this, because this will get messy, but I'm wondering what I might be doing wrong there, or if PHP doesn't support this and why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP is right when invoke fatal error `Call to undefined method stdClass::city()` because object `$class->address('name')` **has no method** `city`.
Intead, this object **has property** `city` which is instance of Closure Class (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)
You can verify this: `var_dump($class->address('name')->city)`

I found the way to call this anonymous function is:

```php
$closure = $class->address('name')->city;
$closure('class');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Sadly it is not possible within stdClass, but there is a workaround -- [PHP Anonymous Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12391546/145678).

```
// define by passing in constructor
$anonim_obj = new AnObj(array(
    "foo" => function() { echo "foo"; }, 
    "bar" => function($bar) { echo $bar; } 
));

$anonim_obj->foo(); // prints "foo"
$anonim_obj->bar("hello, world"); // prints "hello, world"
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is not supported by PHP, and you must use the `call_user_func()` or `call_user_func_array()` functions to call closures assigned to class properties (usually you can use `__call()` to do this, but in your case, the class is `stdClass`, so this isn't possible).