# Calling anonymous function in object converted from associative array

Tags: php, object, php-5.5

According to [Jason's suggestion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php#84292) about quick and dirty one-liner objects, I tried to create methods:

```
$obj = (object)array(
  "handler" => function() { return "Doom"; }
);
```

Calling it the intuitive way fails:

```
echo $obj->handler();
//Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::handler()
```

But this way works:

```
$fnptr = $obj->handler;
echo $fnptr();
// "Doom"
```

Albeit calling it from associative array (not object) runs without fatal error:

```
$arr = array(
  "handler" => function() { return "Doom"; }
);
echo $arr["handler"]();
// "Doom"
```

Can you explain what's going on behind the scene? (I run on PHP 5.5.8)

Comment: Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359793/3647441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What PHP is trying to do here:

```
echo $obj->handler();
```

Is simply trying to call a normal method. But this method isn't defined, so you get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::handler()

But when you do:

```
$fnptr = $obj->handler;
echo $fnptr();
```

You assign the value of the property `handler`, which is an anonymous function, to the variable `$fnptr`. And then PHP doesn't try to call a method, it just calls your anonymous function and it works.

The same when you have an array element, which contains an anonymous function. PHP doesn't try to call a method, it just calls the anonymous function.

So there is no way you can get it to work like this:

```
echo $obj->handler();
```

For an object, since it always will try to call a method.

Comment: Is there any syntactic sugar to call the handler directly? Something like `echo {$obj->handler}()`?

Comment: @JanTuroň No, there is no way around it to assign it to a tmp variable.

Comment: @JanTuroň The only thing I could think of is to use the magic method `__call()`, e.g. https://3v4l.org/pfoR8

Comment: `call_user_func($obj->handler)` would work, though this issn't much better.