# Anonymous class construction

Tags: php, class, namespaces, php-7, anonymous-class

I need an idea to create anonymous class on PHP. I don't know how I can works.

**See my limitations**:

- On PHP you can't make anonymous class, like anonymous function (like `class {}`);
- On PHP you don't have class scope (except in namespaces, but it have the same problem below);
- On PHP you can't use variables to specify the class name (like `class $name {}`);
- I don't have access to install the `runkit` PECL.

**What I need, and why**:

Well, I need create a function called ie `create_class()` that receives a key name and a *anonymous class*. It'll be useful for me because I want use different name class symbols that PHP can't accept. For instance:

```
<?php

  create_class('it.is.an.example', function() {
    return class { ... }
  });

  $obj = create_object('it.is.an.example');

?>
```

So, I need an idea that accept this use. I need it because on my framework I have this path: `/modules/site/_login/models/path/to/model.php`. So, the `model.php` need to declare a new class called `site.login/path.to.model`.

On call `create_object()` if the internal cache have a `$class` definition (like `it.is.an.example` it simply return the new class object. If not, need load. So I will use the `$class` content to search fastly what is the class file.

Comment: PHP's lack of anonymous classes is extremely restrictive.

Comment: You may want to look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6384431/3933332

Comment: Why you have to use invalid class names? Why can't you just substitute these ´.´'s by, let's say, `_`'s?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Just an example.

Comment: This question and all of the answers are extremely dated. This entire thing needs to be closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In PHP 7.0 there will be [anonymous classes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes). I don't fully understand your question, but your `create_class()` function might look like this:

```
function create_class(string $key, array &$repository) {
    $obj = new class($key) {
        private $key;
        function __construct($key) {
            $this->key = $key;
        }
    };
    $repository[$key] = $obj;
    return $obj;
}
```

This will instantiate an object with an anonymous class type and register it into the `$repository`. To get an object out you use the key you created it with: `$repository['it.is.an.example']`.

Comment: Note that anonymous classes can also `extends` other classes and `implements` interfaces ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can create a dummy class using stdClass

```
$the_obj = new stdClass();
```

Comment: Can't attach methods to `stdClass`

Answer (score 6):

So basically you want to implement a factory pattern.

```
Class Factory() {
  static $cache = array();

  public static getClass($class, Array $params = null) {
    // Need to include the inc or php file in order to create the class
    if (array_key_exists($class, self::$cache) {
      throw new Exception("Class already exists");
    }

    self::$cache[$class] = $class;
    return new $class($params);
  }
}

public youClass1() {
  public __construct(Array $params = null) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Add a cache within to check for duplicates

Comment: Not exactly. I need a method to create anonymous classes, to avoid duplicates. If I declare `foo` twice, it'll fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to to that, you could use `eval()`

```
$code = "class {$className} { ... }";
eval($code);
$obj = new $className ();
```

But the gods won't approve this. You will go to hell if you do it.