# php create object without class

Tags: php

In JavaScript, you can easiliy create an object without a class by:

```
 myObj = {};
 myObj.abc = "aaaa";
```

For PHP I've found this one, but it is nearly 4 years old:
http://www.subclosure.com/php-creating-anonymous-objects-on-the-fly.html

```
$obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');
```

Now with PHP 5.4 in 2013, is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6384474/1606729

Comment: $obj = (object)[]; $obj->someProp = "hey boy";

Comment: PHP's nested, associative arrays might be a good replacement for nested JS objects depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 833, accepted):

you can always use `new stdClass()`. Example code:

```
   $object = new stdClass();
   $object->property = 'Here we go';

   var_dump($object);
   /*
   outputs:

   object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
      ["property"]=>
      string(10) "Here we go"
    }
   */
```

Also as of PHP 5.4 you can get same output with:

```
$object = (object) ['property' => 'Here we go'];
```

Comment: +1 for the PHP 5.4 method, this makes code shorter, more readable, especially when you have several items to add to the object.

Comment: If you are looking at turning a nested array into an object, I'd recommend using `json_decode(json_encode($array))` which will turn the entire array into a nested stdClass object.

If you use `(object) $array` it will only convert the first layer into an object, everything nested inside that will remain an array.

Comment: Another way, using single json_decode, is passing a JSON-string:

 $object = json_decode('{"property": {"foo": "bar"}, "hello": "world"}');

Comment: @DavidRouten That was super super helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidRouten Seems like PHP7.4 (or even earlier?) now also creates nested objects when you use (object) $array.