# Getting siblings of array of functions

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the sibling functions of a function inside of an array?

I have an array of functions, similar to:

```
$thingy = [
  'do_something' => function() {
    // call $thingy['do_something_else']()?
  },

  'do_something_else' => function() {

    return 1234;
  }
];
```

Is there a way that I can call `do_something_else` from `do_something`? In other languages, like javascript, you should be able to use `this` or can use the variable name `thingy`.

Comment: Is there a reason this couldn't be an Object?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do what you want implicitly, short of declaring the functions as methods of a class (*instead* of members of an array). The misleading thing is that in JavaScript, the functions have a `this` name that is implicitly the parent object, but doesn't *have* to be. You can reassign it using `.bind` or via various other means. In fact, it's the source of major confusion in JavaScript.

Comment: @RichardChristensen Not really, but it is easier to dynamically add functions into it (not having to use `create_function`) and I was doing a few array functions on to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can achieve this by passing `$thingy` by reference:

```
$thingy = [
    'do_something' => function() use (&$thingy) {
        echo $thingy['do_something_else'](); // just an example
    },
    'do_something_else' => function() {
        return 1234;
    }
];
```

Example usage:

```
$thingy['do_something']();
```

Output:

```
1234
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/122061)

Answer (score 1):

Did a little digging and if you would rather use an object instead of an array. You can use this little php script found:

https://gist.github.com/Mihailoff/3700483

check out an question similar to yours:

[Creating anonymous objects in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384431/creating-anonymous-objects-in-php/12391546#12391546)

it allows for you to create `AnObj()` which then allows you to keep an OOP approach when creating anonymous functions.

using the above linked php file you could do this.

```
$thingy = new AnObj(array(
    'do_something' => function(){
        echo 'do_something';
    },
    'do_something_else' => function( $thingy ){
        $thingy->do_something();
        echo 'do_something_else';
    }
));

$thingy->do_something_else( $thingy );
```

It's just my personal preference to use Objects whenever possible.

Comment: The OP is already using Closure objects, which is a pretty neat way as it is. I don't think there's a need for a separate class just for this. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: Well as you can see you can pass `$thingy` to the `do_something_else()` function which allows for a more dynamic coding process which can allow for more `$thingies` which all have a slightly different `do_something()` function to be passed to the original `$thingy`. where as using an array you would always have to define $thingy every time something changed. Which for me allows for a more code reusability and loosely coupled design. Of course it really is a matter of preference.

Comment: Right. It depends on the use-case, though. +1 for an alternative approach!