# What is the benefit of using PDO::FETCH_CLASS and when to use it

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I wonder when do I have to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS and what is the benefit of using it rather than using other fetch method like PDO::FETCH_ASSOC?

Comment: What is your other fetch method?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to know the difference and benefits of using either  `PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` or `PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`?

Comment: yes. comparing with PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Comment: well , my comment is stupid ; but it's all explain here : http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: i know about that, but i still didn't get it, when do i should use FETCH_CLASS meanwhile i can do it by using FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: FETCH_CLASS return a new instance => you can call some function.
FETCH_ASSOC return an array => you can print some result.

Many case you will want an instance instead of an array of value

Comment: can you tell me in what case or example? that's my point, i need to know in what case :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you like or need.

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` makes fetch return an associative array.

`PDO::FETCH_OBJ` is similar, but return an 'anonymous object' with properties. Note that actually 'anonymous object' [is the wrong term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384431/creating-anonymous-objects-in-php), but the PHP documentation [also uses it](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). It refers to an object that inherites from [StdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php).

`PDO::FETCH_CLASS` is a variation to that. It doesn't use StdClass, but creates an object of a specific (given) class type and tries to map column values to properties of that object.

This is useful if you don't want to use StdClass, but want to use a 'smart' object instead. For instance if you have a User table with FirstName and LastName, you could let PDO::fetch return a `User` object that implements a `getFullName` method that returns the concatenated first and last name. StdClass won't have this method, and neither will your array.

But still, if you like working with arrays, there is no need for you to switch to any of the other two. Use what you like best.

Comment: so if for some case i need some information from article table, it is better to use assoc rather than extract it into a class?

Comment: It's not better or worse. It's just a matter of opinion. You can use either.

Comment: I see, so it just about which style we like to use?

Comment: If you wanted to use ORM  to access your data, you'd use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, for example.

Comment: ok then thanks for explain