# Strange behaviour concatenating string in a PHP anonymous object

Tags: php, object

Maybe someone can help explain the strange behaviour with this anon object:

```
$equipTest = (object) [
  $leakageLimit = "",
  $description = "",
  $location = "",
  $text = "",
 ];
$description = "";
```

In the following loop, I can assign values to `$leakageLimit` with no issues.

```
$equipTest->leakageLimit = $temp;
```

But `$location` will not let me concatenate to it with out an error/notice:

```
$equipTest->location .= $temp;
```

Results in:

> Notice (8): Undefined property: `stdClass::$location`

As it did for `$equipTest->description` until I declared a temp var outside the loop. I assigned values to the temp description in the loop with:

```
$description .= $temp;
```

And then assigned it to the object at the end of the loop with:

```
$equipTest->$description = $description;
```

Why can't I concatenate to this anonymous object?  It was OK before when I had it as part of a fully declared class.

Comment: Start with `print_r($equipTest)` I bet you'll be suprised

Comment: How to create anonymous object with php7. Checkout these links: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384431/creating-anonymous-objects-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
[
  $leakageLimit = "",
  $description = "",
  $location = "",
  $text = "",
]
```

does not mean

> create array with four **named** elements and init each of them with empty string.

It means

> create array of four **numeric-indexed** elements and set value of every element as a result of assigning an empty string to a variable.

And result of assigning is a value being assigned, i.e. - empty string.

So, if you

```
print_r([
  $leakageLimit = "",
  $description = "",
  $location = "",
  $text = "",
]);
```

you will see array with 4 empty values. And also your variables `$leakageLimit`, `$description`, `$location`, `$text` will be set to empty string.

So, if you want to create object with four named properties, your code is:

```
$equipTest = (object) [
  'leakageLimit' => "",
  'description' => "",
  'location' => "",
  'text' => "",
];
```

Comment: Aghh!  I know this now I see it.  My only defence your honor is I started coded at 7 this morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is you're casting an `array` to an `object`. That produces unpredictable things sometimes, and it has here. If you `var_dump($equipTest)` what you'll get back is

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

You'll note that it didn't keep the keys like you were expecting. When you do

```
$equipTest->leakageLimit = 'someval';
```

It actually creates the variable.

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["leakageLimit"]=>
  string(7) "someval"
}
```

If I were you, I'd make a class that defines these values first, then you can concatenate them. It avoids [the nasty side effects of casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php)