# Different price depending on day of week PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and I would like to display a different price for my product according to the day of the week. For example on Mondays the price should be 50% off, on Wednesdays it should have a 10% more expensive and so on.
I was thinking of using a function with a switch statement but I can't make it to work. Hope somebody can give me some tips!

```
    function day_of_week($day) {
    $day = "Monday";

    switch ($day) {
        case "Monday":
            $key['price'] / 2;
            break;
        case "Wednesday":
            $key['price'] * 1.1;
            break;
        case "Friday":
            if($key['price'] >= 200) {
                $key['price'] - 20;
            }   
    }

}
Today's price:
<?php echo day_of_week($day); ?>
```

Comment: Don’t assign a value to $day within the function. It will overwrite whatever you pass to the function parameter.

Comment: @LeanderIversen Hi! I've put it outside the function but nothing is changing. Where should I put it?

Comment: Many problems. You're overwriting `$day` so it will always be "Monday". Where did `$key` come from? You aren't doing anything with the result of whatever calculation you perform on `$key['price']`. You're not returning the result from your function.

Comment: Outside the function is fine. You also need a return statement, e.g return $key[‘price’] / 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments there were many issues like $day reinitializing again and $key not in the function scope and not returning anything etc...

Following is the working code:

```php
<?php
$day = date('l');
$key['price'] = 2000;
function day_of_week($day , $price) {

    switch ($day) {
        case "Monday":
            return $price / 2;
        case "Wednesday":
            return $price * 1.1;
        case "Friday":
            if($price >= 200) {
                return $price - 20;
            }
    }
    return $price;
}
echo "Price for ".$day.": ".day_of_week($day, $key['price']);

 ?>
```

Another possible way!

```php
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Ussaid Iqbal
 * Date: 10/14/18
 * Time: 4:09 PM
 */
$day = "Wednesday";
$key["price"] = 2000;

function day_of_week($day) {
    global $key;
    switch ($day) {
        case "Monday":
            return $key["price"] / 2;
        case "Wednesday":
            return $key["price"] * 1.1;
        case "Friday":
            if($key["price"] >= 200) {
                return $key["price"] - 20;
            }
    }
    return $key["price"];
}
echo "Today's price: ".day_of_week($day);

 ?>
```

Comment: It is working! Many thanks! Can you explain me how $key['price'] = 2000 works? I don't really understand it.

Comment: The `break;` for "Wednesday" isn't really necessary since you have a return before it :-)

Comment: I assumed it was stored in an array now that array is defined outside of the function lets say globally so to access that variable you need to pass it through the function or call **global $WhateverVariableYouNeedInsideFunction;** at the start of function.

Comment: Just a note about the `$price`-variable. It should be passed to the function (like this answer suggests). Using `global` is an anti-pattern and should always be avoided whenever possible (which it more or less always is if you write your code using best practices).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `global` constants are fine while using `global` for non-constant variables should be avoided. :-)

Comment: If you have variables as constants which you pass around using `global`, you have a code smell already. Variables are variable, constants are constant. Constants are global by design and don't need `global`. Like I said, if you need to use the `global` keyword, you're most likely not following best practices to begin with.

Comment: Your comments were a bit unclear :-) I was only talking about the `global` keyword.

Comment: @UssaidIqbal Thanks! The only problem I am getting is that eventhougt it is Sunday today, the program keeps applying the 50% off which should only be on Mondays.

Comment: @Nebula just tested it's working fine, check the updated answer along with the day printed!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am still a learner, and i learn by helping others. So maybe you are right, can you explain further why we should avoid using global?

Comment: @UssaidIqbal he just told you why

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [anonymous object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384431/creating-anonymous-objects-in-php) as a controller to do this. It would require creating [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to execute the closure.

```
$priceChart = (object)
[
    'monday' => function($price) {
        return (int) $price / 2;
    },
    'wednesday' => function($price) {
        return (int) $price * 1.1;
    },
    'friday' => function($price) {
        return (int) $price > 200 ? (int) $price - 20 : (int) $price;
    }
];

$price = 20.00; // Can be of type string
$currentDay = 'WednEsdAy'; // Capitals do not matter or use date('l');
$newPrice = isset($priceChart->{strtolower($currentDay)}) ? call_user_func_array($priceChart->{strtolower($currentDay)}, [$price]) : $price;
```

You can [see a working example](https://3v4l.org/AAQ86) over at 3v4l.